# search value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and search for the value 100 - the result should gives me the key of the array. this works like this:

```
$myArray = array(
        array(
            'score'   => '100',
            'name'    => 'Sam',
            'subject' => 'Data Structures'
        ),
        array(
            'score'   => '200',
            'name'    => 'Tanya',
            'subject' => 'Advanced Algorithms'
        ),
        array(
            'score'   => '300',
            'name'    => 'Jack',
            'subject' => 'Distributed Computing'
        )
    );
      
$id = array_search('100', array_column($myArray, 'score'));
```

But now the "column" score should be an array, too:

```
$myArray = array(
        array(
            'score'   => array('100','200'),
            'name'    => 'Sam',
            'subject' => 'Data Structures'
        ),
        array(
            'score'   => array('300','400'),
            'name'    => 'Tanya',
            'subject' => 'Advanced Algorithms'
        ),
        array(
            'score'   => array('500','600'),
            'name'    => 'Jack',
            'subject' => 'Distributed Computing'
        )
    );
```

But now my array_search part doesn't work.
How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to write a loop, there's no built-in function for this.

Comment: `foreach (array_column($myArray, 'score') => $index => $array) ...`

Comment: first `=>` to `as` : `foreach (array_column($myArray, 'score') as $index => $array) ...` @barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works exactly the same way as your first block

```
$id = array_search(100, array_merge(array_column(array_column($myArray, 'score'), 0), array_column(array_column($myArray, 'score'), 1)));
```

OR you can write it this way for readability

```
$tempArray1 = array_column(array_column($myArray, 'score'), 0);
$tempArray2 = array_column(array_column($myArray, 'score'), 1);
$myArray2 = array_merge($tempArray1, $tempArray2);
    

      
$id = array_search('100', $myArray2);
```

Comment: thank you so much !! you made my day ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` and then use `in_array` on the `scores` key thus returning arrays that have a value of `100`.

```
array_filter($myArray, fn($v) => in_array(100, $v['score']));
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["score"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "100"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "200"
    }
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Sam"
    ["subject"]=>
    string(15) "Data Structures"
  }
}
```

[See it working over at 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/2POb0)